# Pegar raio de um círculo da Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

Olá, estou precisando pegar o raio de um círculo criado no Openlayers 3. Alguém sabe como fazer?

[Aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/Isaabela/80evg6vn/2/#&togetherjs=LshsGebaQq) tem o exemplo do mapa com a possibilidade de criar os círculos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei a seguinte solução que funcionou muito bem:

```
draw.on('drawend', function(evt){
  var feature = evt.feature;
  var p = feature.getGeometry();
  var radius = p.getRadius();
  console.log(radius);
});
```